# How to print scenario name when running each scenario in capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara

I want the scenario name to be printed in console. I am using Rspec and Capybara and selenium in my framework.
Can you please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to choose a formatter that already does that for you. RSpec ships with a number of built-in formatters and `documentation` will print the scenario name - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/command-line/format-option .  There are also a number of third party formatter options, or you can write your own custom formatter - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/formatters/custom-formatters